# Not able to give remote access to mongodb server to other systems which are is in same wifi network on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

When I set bindIp of mongod.conf file as my wifi router's default gateway i.e bindIp:127.0.0.1,198.168.3.1. my MongoDB server stops and I get following error when I check its status.

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-01-23 17:42:38 IST; 1s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3046 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited
 Main PID: 3046 (code=exited, status=48)

Jan 23 17:42:38 sarvahapc systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jan 23 17:42:38 sarvahapc systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=
Jan 23 17:42:38 sarvahapc systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 23 17:42:38 sarvahapc systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-c
lines 1-11/11 (END)
```

But when I set bindIp: 0.0.0.0 in mongod.conf file my MongoDB server runs smoothly and it allows remote access to my MongoDB server for other systems which are in my wifi network.

I want to give remote access to my MongoDB server to other systems which are in my wifi network. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi. Try setting bindIp:198.168.3.1. Then, sudo service mongod restart. To connect from another device on the same Wi-Fi network, use the IP set previously.

Comment: I tried to used bindIp:198.168.3.1 also but it gives same error

Comment: Exit code 48 means the port is already in use. Perhaps there is a another mongod process running already?

Comment: Nope I did checkd if any instance is running or not...even i restarted the system still i get same error.